# how to let the rust code using local use command

Tags: intellij-idea, rust, intellij-rust

I have a write a rust code look like this:

```
fn find_channel(request: &ChannelRequest) -> Box<dyn BoxableExpression<crate::model::diesel::dolphin::dolphin_schema::rss_sub_source::table, DB, SqlType=Bool> + '_> {
    use crate::model::diesel::dolphin::dolphin_schema::rss_sub_source::dsl::*;
    match request {
        ChannelRequest { editorPick, .. } if editorPick.unwrap_or(0) == 1 => Box::new(crate::model::diesel::dolphin::dolphin_schema::rss_sub_source::dsl::editor_pick.eq(editorPick)),
        ChannelRequest{ minimalReputation, ..} if minimalReputation.unwrap_or(0) > 0 => Box::new(crate::model::diesel::dolphin::dolphin_schema::rss_sub_source::dsl::reputation.gt(minimalReputation)),
        _ => Box::new(crate::model::diesel::dolphin::dolphin_schema::rss_sub_source::dsl::editor_pick.eq(0))
    }
}
```

Now I want to make the code more shorter, and remove `crate::model::diesel::dolphin::dolphin_schema::rss_sub_source::dsl::` and want to let the `editor_pick` to use local function import command. To my surprise, the IDE still tell me to import the `crate::model::diesel::dolphin::dolphin_schema::rss_sub_source::dsl::`, why still need import even through imported in the function? what should I to to remove the package path from the code and make the code more shorter and cleaner? is it possible to remove the package path from code? This is the intellij tips from IDE:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does `cargo`/`rustc` accept the code? It's possible that IntelliJ Rust is buggy in this case.

Comment: I found the cargo build accept the code, but the intellij rust did not give the right tips. Thank you! You save my time@Solomon Ucko